# Iterate through an ArrayList + Observer Pattern

Tags: java, loops, design-patterns, arraylist, observer-pattern

I have recently tried programming various versions of Iterator and Observer Patterns in Java, but currently I'm stuck at the implementation of both in one project:

What I'm trying to accomplish is to iterate through an ArrayList, which contains elements of type  and after each iteration-process to inform the Observer about the change and the containing element.
Also I want to be able to choose the "type" of iterator in my separate classes

Edit: I finally finished the project, hopefully this is the correct version of a "Observer Iterator", any tips on how to improve the code are greatly appreciated, but thanks to everybodys' encouraging tips.

Code:

First of all, the helper class for the Observer interface, which implements the update method. Changes with every iteration process and prints out the element.

```
package iteratorObserver;

import java.util.List;

public class ConcreteObserver implements Observer{

    @Override
    public void update(String element) {
        System.out.println("The current element is: " + element);

    }

}
```

The actual Observer interface:

```
package iteratorObserver;

public interface Observer<E> {

    void update(String element);

}
```

Following that, the same by using a ConcreteSubject and an abstract class Subject
The observer pattern requires the getState and setState, so I integrated both into the next method. Getting the element by iterator.next aswell as setting it.

```
package iteratorObserver;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class ConcreteSubject<E>  extends Subject implements IteratorStandardFilter<E>{

    List<String> listElements = new ArrayList<String>();
    private int index;
    private Iterator<E> iterator;

    public ConcreteSubject(Iterator<E> iterator, List<String> listElements){
    index = 0;
    this.iterator = iterator;
    this.listElements = listElements;
    }

    public void addElement(String element) {
        listElements.add(element);
        notifyObservers(element);
    }

    // check the size of the elements list and return if there are still 
    // elements left out
    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        if ((listElements.size() == index))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    // iterate to the next element, not sure if it's overridden, since the 
    // actual next method of the iterator is still in use
    @Override
    public E next() {
        E result = iterator.next();
        index++;
        notifyObservers((String) result);
        return result;
    }


}
```

Subject class, only used for the standard observer methods

```
package iteratorObserver;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Subject {

    public List<Observer> listObservers = new ArrayList<Observer>();

    public void addObserver(Observer observer){
        listObservers.add(observer);
    }

    public void removeObserver(Observer observer){
        listObservers.remove(observer);
    }

    public <E> void notifyObservers(String element){
        for(Observer observerHelp : listObservers){
            observerHelp.update(element);
        }
    }
 }
```

Since i want to add various filters, not only the standard list-iterator, i added a class IteratorStandardFilter, as you can see here:

```
package iteratorObserver;

import java.util.Iterator;

public interface IteratorStandardFilter<E> extends Iterator<E> {

    public boolean hasNext();
    public E next();
}
```

And finally, the Test method, the main:

```
package iteratorObserver;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class iteratorObserverMain {

    public static void main(String [] args){

        List<String> listElements = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        listElements.add("hello");
        listElements.add("there");
        listElements.add("everybody");
        listElements.add("it");
        listElements.add("works");
        listElements.add("Thanks for your help. Nice and encouraging forum");

        Iterator<String> iterator = listElements.iterator();
        ConcreteSubject<String> concreteSubject = new ConcreteSubject<String>(iterator, listElements);
        concreteSubject.addObserver(new ConcreteObserver());

        while(concreteSubject.hasNext()){
            concreteSubject.next();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your objective is not clear. What are you trying to make Observable? What have you tried so far?

Comment: That sounds like some kind of homework to me. Nevertheless am I right when the list you are iterating is the subject you want to observe? Than your IteratorStandardFilter can be labeled as subject. This needs to know it's observers so you might spend it a `register(Observer o)` method. Does that help?

Comment: Fairly certain you'll need a list of your observables if you want to "notify" them of an event. https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer

Comment: Okay so i tried to write down some classes, but this is how far I've come, I've just started it today so the progress is not that impressive...

I'm going to post it into the Main-Post as an Edit

Comment: No we had the Observer and Iterator pattern in our course, but i can assure you that it's not a homework assignment, I just want to finally get it.

Yeah i want to observe the list and iterate over the elements in that said list, so i can send the current element to the observer.

I'm going to look into it later in the evening, but that's really helpful, thank you @ TobiSH

Comment: @ cricket_007 I will update the Main-Post, but i think i already completed the list of observables, aswell as the methods needed for the Subject, i think the suggested "register (Observer o)" method is the same as my "addObserver" method

Comment: I edited my main post, i appreciate any further tips on how to improve the project, for now I think it is finished. Thanks for your help.